# Should I re-authenticate once Socket.io upgrades to WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, engine.io

When using Socket.io in NodeJS, it creates a polling transport first and then tries to upgrade it to a websocket on the side. During the initial polling request, it is possible to send headers to the server and use information in these to do authentication. That socket is then marked as safe, and every request coming after the initial one is considered coming from the same user.

This assumption is never stated directly in Socket.io documentation, but several examples uses middleware (which is only run on initial connection setup) to handle authentication.

My question is, does this certainty carry over when the polling transport is upgraded to a websocket? Should I re-authenticate once the socket presents and "upgrade" event? And am I certain that a mallicius client won't be able to establish a websocket directly, without first going through the polling step?

Comment: As far as i know, you don't need to re-auth once you done and client won't be able to establish a websocket directly.

Comment: That is also what I'm hoping for, but I'm just not able to find any documentation for it anywhere. Thanks for input though - it affirms that I'm not the only one having this impression.

Comment: Yea as i said, this is what i know for know but I'm using a production node server and it's working without re-auth so